# Converting a line of text into another format with jq avoiding 'if-then-else'

Tags: json, jq

Using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), I want to convert the input `A B=1 C= D=2` to `"A", "B": "1", "C": "", "D": "2"`

I came up with the solution

```bash
jq -Rr '. / " " | map(. / "=" | "\"\(.[0])\"" + (if .[1] != null then ": \"\(.[1])\"" else "" end)) | join(", ")'
```

I am sure there is a more elegant way that avoids the `if-then-else`.
Can you help me shorten the expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
jq -Rr '
    . / " " |
    map(. / "=" |
          "\"" + join("\": \"") + "\""
       ) |
    join(", ")
' input.json
```

Comment: another `join` is the trick ... thanks!